# RemoteApp: end disconnected sessions except for some users

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, remoteapp

I have a Windows Server 2016 running some RemoteApps, and I configured it to automatically **end sessions** if they are **disconnected for 5 minutes** or if they are **idle for 15 minutes**, like this:

[image]

The problem is that even normal Remote Desktop connections are ended in this way, and I don't want this behaviour for a list of users.

- how I can configure this only for RemoteApp and not for Remote Desktop connections?
- how I can exclude a list of users from this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to set that windows as set as you want for your Remote Desktop User and Im would set a GPO that target users that use remote apps.

The setting set by my example below exist in Computer Configuration too, but it would mean all user get it on your server.

- Create a AD group, to list all users that use Remote App.
- Create a User GPO, targetting a user OU; with that setting set to 15, or change the settings you need.

  - **User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits**
- Create a WMI Filter on that GPO that will make the GPO execute only on Terminal Server;

  - **Select * From Win32_TerminalServiceSetting Where TerminalServerMode=1**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use your RD sessions hosts both for RemoteApp and for "full destkop" connections.

If that's the case... it shouldn't, because you must dedicate RD Session Hosts either for RemoteApp OR for Remote Desktop.

You have to create one collection with your remote apps, and another one without remote apps so that users will use the full desktop.

Comment: Thanks! I can't create a new collection without adding another RD Session Host, right? I tried to deploy a new RDS role on the same server but I can only make a new Virtual machine-based desktop environment. Should I install a new server to have what you said?

Comment: Correct ! You have to install another server, add the session host role, add it to a new collection and don't publish remote app on this collection, so you can use this collection to connect to the full desktop and you will be able to set the timeouts you want since it's separated from you Remote App collection. I can't provide screenshots right now, but when you created a collection, there is a little text saying that publishing Remote apps will unpublish the remote desktop :)

Comment: Thanks! One ore question: so what about simply install a new server from scratch and use it for Remote Desktop creating a new collection on it (and not on the first one)? Just to let me share the same RDS licenses with the first server?

Comment: You can, but I think that this will be harder to manage, you will end up with two broker instead of one with a centralized view / management.